# Starting a sentence with 'With us"

Tags: writing-advice

I have been told that one should not start a sentence with 'With us". And to be honest, I have never seen it in use either.

So, is it correct to say - "With us, you get access to the finest hotel deals in Florence"

Comment: It doesn't sound ungrammatical if the preceding sentence was something like "With them, you get ...". What specific objection were you given about sentences that start with "With us"? In what context was the discussion framed?

Comment: No specific references were given, it was just stated as a rule to me (just like, never start a sentence with But).

Comment: There’s considerable freedom in how words are used. So-called ‘rules’ tend to be framed to address specific or even generic instances of poor phrasing. But they don’t preclude natural-sounding usage where appropriate (e.g. starting this sentence with the word *but*). I’ve voted to refer this question to [ell.se], where discussion of such rules (of thumb) of English seems more at home. It can help for you to add some examples cited by whoever produced your rule, where sentences starting with “with us” sound awkward.

Comment: There is no specific reason *in general* that you can't use "with us" to start a sentence, a phrase or a paragraph. Context is all that matters there… so what are you really asking? Can you Post two examples?

"With us, (anything)…" is fine *so long as it contradicts something that went before*. Otherwise no, it's never an acceptable *start*.

Comment: I just wonder how it is that this question has not been migrated already...

Comment: With us in the lead, the crowd moved to the other room.

Comment: *it was just stated as a rule to me* - “There are no rules in English, only guidance. Some guidance looks like a rule; it probably isn't."

Comment: Jai Hind. Are you jabbering to your friends or writing a dissertation? :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. You can also say it this way...

"With us being the guardians of galaxy, you're now safe to roam around the world"

Comment: You might, if that was "with us *as* the guardians"